# Move space from one partition to another partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I want to get 50 GB from my ubuntu machine(bootcamp), to my macintosh. I have released the 50 GB from my ubuntu machine with gparted, but i dont know to transfer it over to my mac.

Thanks

[image: MyGparted]

Answer (score 0):

**Remember:** Backup any data, before you begin messing with partitions!

**Warning**: I don't know about dual-booting on Mac!

But if you right-click the /sda4 partition you should be able to find a menu called "Resize/Move".
You need to move that partition "to the right".
That will bring your free space next to the sda3 partition.
Then you can move sda3, and then finally expand sda2 into the free space.

Also notice that you can't do this while your system is running off any of these partitions. Booting from a usb, and running gparted through there is usually the way to go.

**Warning**: (again) I don't know about dual-booting on Mac! If the Mac OS can find the partition after it has been resized / moved is not sure. Someone else perhaps can help with that.